# how to get in app Purchase to work

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a practice in app purchases the removes the iAds from the screen buy simple running a function called remove ads. all it does is set the practice/test iAd to a position that is off the screen the problem is that this is my first time doing in app purchases. i made the in app purchases an iTunes connect but i can get it to work here. does anybody now how to do a in app purchase?  Thanks I'm using swift in Xcode and the GoHome SKlabel simple take you back to the home screen so don't mind it. Im using SpritKit.

Code:

```
 import Foundation
 import AVFoundation
 import SpriteKit
 import GameKit
 import UIKit
 import StoreKit

 class ThirdScene: SKScene,SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate,      SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{

let RemoveaddsButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayAltenative")
let RestorePurchases = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StopButton")
let GoHome = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RedHomeButton")
var iAdLabel = SKLabelNode()
var RemoveAdvertisment = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
   //-----------------------------------------------------------
      var iAdLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "OriyaSangamMN-Bold")
    iAdLabel.text = "I am An Advertisment"
    iAdLabel.fontSize = 20
    iAdLabel.zPosition = 20
    iAdLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    iAdLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y:     self.frame.size.height * 0.70)
    self.addChild(iAdLabel)
   //--------------------------------------------------------
    self.RemoveaddsButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width *  0.70, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.20)
    RemoveaddsButton.zPosition = 100
    RemoveaddsButton.size = CGSize(width: 115, height: 170)
    self.addChild(self.RemoveaddsButton)
    //-----------------------------------------------------
self.RemoveAdvertisment.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.70, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.28)
     RemoveAdvertisment.text = "Remove Adds here"
     RemoveAdvertisment.zPosition = 100
     RemoveAdvertisment.fontSize = 15
    self.addChild(self.RemoveAdvertisment)
     //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.GoHome.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.80, y:  self.frame.size.height * 0.90)
    GoHome.zPosition = 100
    GoHome.size = CGSize(width: 115, height: 170)
    self.addChild(self.GoHome)
    //------------------------------
   // Set IAPS
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("Advertisement are enabled is enabled, loading")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "SkateLinesNolliePackage");
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please Buy Remove Advertisments")
    }
}
func removeAds() {
    CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height * 10.70)

        }

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()


func buyProduct() {
    let payment: SKPayment = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

}
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("Just Requested A product")
    var myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        println("product added")
        println(product.productIdentifier)
        println(product.localizedTitle)
        println(product.localizedDescription)
        println(product.price)
        list.append(product as! SKProduct)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions are now restored")
    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
        switch prodID {
        case "SkateLine.iap.removeads":
            println("Now Removing ads")
            removeAds()
         default:
            println("Must buy remove ads")
        }

    }
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)
        switch trans.transactionState {
         case .Purchased:
            println("buy, ok unlock Remove ads here")
            println(p.productIdentifier)
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "SkateLinesNolliePackage":
                println("removeing the ads now")
                removeAds()
            default:
                println("Buy Remove ads")
            }
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;
        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    println("finishing Transaction")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
{
    println("remove all trans");
}
func restoreyourpurchases() {
     println("Now Your purchases are restored")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.RemoveaddsButton {
            for product in list {
                var prodID = product.productIdentifier
                if(prodID == "SkateLinesNolliePackage") {
                    p = product
                    buyProduct()
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        let location2 = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.RestorePurchases {
                restoreyourpurchases()

        }

        let location3 = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.GoHome {

                println(" PlayBtn Going to game play.")
                var scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                let sKView = self.view! as SKView
                sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.size = sKView.bounds.size
                let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.45)
                sKView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)


  }
  }
  }
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check my question and my answer here about IAPs: [My IAP isn't working. Bugs at func Paymentqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue)

It contains working code for IAPs to remove ads and a few tips. I hope that helps you !

Here is the full IAP code :

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("val") != nil {
            print("Has a value.")
            banner.removeFromSuperview()
            bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
            outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
            outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
            removeInterFrom = 1
        }
        else {
            print("No Value.")
        }

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            print("IAP is enabled, loading...")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects:"IAP id")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else{
            print("Please enable IAPS")

        }

    }


    //IAP Ads

    @IBAction func removeAds(sender: UIButton) {
        for product in list{
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodID == "IAP id"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    //IAP Functions

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func removeAds(){
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
        bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
        outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
        outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
        let theValue = 10
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theValue, forKey: "val")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func buyProduct(){
        print("Buy: "+p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment (product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Product Request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct{
            print("Product Added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Add Payment")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState{
            case .Purchased:
                print("IAP unlocked")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID{
                case "IAP id":
                    print("Remove Ads")
                    removeAds()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .Failed:
                print ("Buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("default: Error")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Purchases Restored")

        _ = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID{
            case "IAP id":
                print("Remove Ads")
                removeAds()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


        }
    }
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction){
        print("Finshed Transaction")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Remove Transaction")
    }
}
```

Put:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear