# StoreKit "This in-app purchase has already been bought" message

Tags: callback, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm using StoreKit to provide a way for my users to remove ads from my app.

When my app starts, I call restoreCompletedTransactions to handle the case of a user having already bought the item.

But in the following scenario:

- log with a user
- buy the ads free licence
- logout from the iTunes & App Store (from the settings)
- start the app (restore won't work as there is no user logged in)
- buy the licence, StoreKit will ask for a user / pwd, set the same user / pwd as in 1st step

Then I get the "This in-app purchase has already been bought" message. Which could be fine, but... There is absolutely no callback called, which makes me unable to remove the modal progress bar I display when the user presses the "Buy" button, and to remove my ads.

Is there any solution (I saw this post, which does not address my problem [iOS "This in-app purchase has already been bought" pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001868/ios-this-in-app-purchase-has-already-been-bought-pop-up))?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer: we shall not call restoreCompletedTransactions on startup, but upon user request only. This was causing the callback not being called...

All this trouble because Apple does not provide a simple way to know if a product has been purchased or not :/

Comment: Hi - I did not understand your response. I am also having the same issue. How do you resolve this issue. I want to get a call back after that dialog box that says "This In-App purchase has already been bought...". so that I can remove my ads too. Please share any code that you may have

Comment: Hi, not sure what have you not understood? You must not call restoreCompletedTransactions when starting the app, but only to react to a user click. Then you'll get the callback.